# Do "lipstick on a pig" and "画蛇添足" share the same meaning?

Tags: idioms, chengyu

Do "lipstick on a pig" and "画蛇添足" share the same meaning?
画蛇添足 means "drawing snake with feet".

Comment: search web using e.g. "中文 lipstick on a pig" get many results, e.g. http://language.chinadaily.com.cn/trans/2009-08/17/content_8579764.htm

Comment: I think the Chinese word (成语) for the *"lipstick on a pig"* is 对牛弹琴.

Comment: more like 東施效顰.

Comment: "lipstick on a pig", I don't know how American think about this phrase, but to me it means "醜人多作怪".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

画蛇添足 means 'ruin things by adding unnecessary, inappropriate addition'

Adding legs on a snake in a painting not only doesn't improve its quality , it actually ruins it by adding unnecessary, inappropriate addition

For example:

Man: "I love you"

Woman: "I love you too"

*So far so good*

Man: "I love you as much as I love my dog"

*Now it is too much information, the second sentence from the man is '蛇足'(unnecessary, inappropriate addition)*

"lipstick on a pig" means something entirely different. It means " wasted effort", a pig is a pig, no matter how much make up you put on it, it can never looked like a pretty lady.